# Pandas combine two dataseries into one series

Tags: python, pandas

I need to combine the dataseries rateScore and rate into one.

This is the current DataFrame I have

```
    rateScore   rate
10  NaN         4.5
11  2.5         NaN
12  4.5         NaN
13  NaN         5.0
..
235 NaN         4.7
236 3.8         NaN
```

This needs to be something like this:

```
    rateScore
10  4.5         
11  2.5         
12  4.5         
13  5.0 
..
235 4.7         
236 3.8
```

The rate column needs to be dropped after merging the series and also for each row, the index number needs stay the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `combine_first` to fill NaN values from a second Series:

```
df['rateScore'] = df['rateScore'].combine_first(df['rateScore'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following with `fillna()`, redifining the `rateScore` column and dropping `rate`:

```
df = df.fillna(0)
df['rateScore'] = df['rateScore'] + df['rate']
df = df.drop(columns='rate')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us do `add`

```
df['rateScore'] = df['rateScore'].add(df['rate'],fill_value=0)
```